# How do to view pdf file in Mobile Device using localhost

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, pdf

As you can see in the image below, there's no preview of it. I tried using google docs.

Here's a photo of the result.
[image]

[image]

Is there any way on how to resolve this one, aside from using pdf.js. I think most of the solution that I found was their website is live and I do not know if this only works at live websites and not locally. Thanks.
PS: The pdfs are okay and not corrupted when I download it.

Comment: `As you can see in the image below, there's no preview of it. ` Preview of what?

Comment: @blackapps pdf file after the `RepositoryFiles/` the `test_update.pdf` specfically.

Comment: So you did not edit your post.